# Using right and left string functions inside c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've written a cs page called Global Validation.  It looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace ClientDPL
{

  public static class StringExtensions
  {
    public static string Right(this string str, int length)
    //Usage: 
    //  string ActiveUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    //  string LoginID = ActiveUser.Right(6);
    {
        return str.Substring(str.Length - length, length);
    }

    public static string Left(this string str, int length)
    //Usage: 
    //  string ActiveUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    //  string LoginID = ActiveUser.Left(6);
    {
        return str.Substring(0, length);
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to use the Left function on a cs page of one of my web pages to get the first 6 characters of a string, like this:

```
string MyOtherString = "Hello World!";
string MyString = MyOtherString.Left(6);
```

I'm getting an error:

> String does not contain a definition of 'Left', and no extension
>   method of 'Left' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found.

I am 100% positive I've used this before, the functions were cannibalized from another project, but I'm just wondering if maybe I somehow needed to hook it into the app somewhere?  There's got to be a step I missed in making these functions usable throughout the application.

Comment: Do you have `using ClientDPL;` in a file where you calling your extensions?

Comment: You could also import the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` library and use [those same functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings(v=vs.110).aspx) that it defines.

Comment: @KennethK. Ugh no, please don't do that.

Comment: @DavidG Why? It's a library. Does the "Visual Basic" in the name scare you?

Comment: @AleksAndreev - OMG.  I'm such an idiot.  Sometimes it's the simplest answer that is the best.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @JohnnyBones consider using ReSharper or Rider: this tools will automatically suggest missing usings (I'm hoping this would not be treated as spam)

Comment: 100% agree with @Aleks Andreev - ReSharper is an amazing tool. Fixes these sort of _gotchas_ all the time

Comment: When I place `StringExtensions` directly in the Namespace of my project I get the extensions. No errors.

Comment: As @KennethK. mentioned, using a library _can_ be better than reinventing the wheel. Your extension method needs to handle things like empty string, length of string checks, etc.  - `"".Left(6);`, `"foo".Left(6);`